# React and CSS: Timing function is not executed correctly

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, css-transforms

React and CSS make nothing but problems in my experience.
The child-section Todo is supposed to smoothly transition to the side, out of bounds. Instead, it just happens immediately. What to change?

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.todo {
  background: var(--geist-background);
  padding: 2rem;
  position: relative; /* For the left property to work*/
  transition: transform 3s ease-in;
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.todo-slide-out {
  position: relative; /* For the left property to work*/
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Move along now</h1>
            <div className={view ? "todo" : "todo-slide-out"}>
                <div className="attributes">
                    <h1>{hardTodo.title}</h1>
                    <p>{hardTodo.content}</p>
                </div>           
                <div className="actions">
                    <button onClick={() => deleteTodo()}>Delete Todo</button>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
```

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-shannon-hyhfj9?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox that reproduce your problem so we can help you ?

Comment: Your `.todo-slide-out` should _extend_ the `.todo` CSS rule instead of being a separate style entirely: change it to `.todo.slide-out` and change your JSX to `<div className={view ? "todo" : "todo slide-out"}>` (note the space)

Comment: @FlorentM. i have added a code sandbox. feel free to check it out, i hope everything is correctly set up over there as it seems that .tsx files are not correctly recognized.

Comment: @Dai, that was the correct answer, it works now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Posting my comment as an answer):

- Your `.todo-slide-out` should extend the `.todo` CSS rule instead of being a separate style entirely.

  - Change the selector from `.todo-slide-out` to `.todo.slide-out`.
  - Change your JSX to `<div className={view ? "todo" : "todo slide-out"}>` (note the space).
- Also, you don't need `position: relative;` if you aren't using `position: absolute` and `top`/`left`/`bottom`/`left`. The `position: relative;` property is not necessary to use `transform:`.

  - You also don't need `transform: translateX(0%);` in `.todo {}` either.

```css
.todo {
  background: var(--geist-background);
  padding: 2rem;
  transition: transform 3s ease-in;
}

.todo.slide-out {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Move along now</h1>
            <div className={view ? "todo" : "todo slide-out"}> <!-- Was "todo-slide-out" but is now "todo slide-out" which corresponds to the ".todo.slide-out" selector. -->
                <div className="attributes">
                    <h1>{hardTodo.title}</h1>
                    <p>{hardTodo.content}</p>
                </div>           
                <div className="actions">
                    <button onClick={() => deleteTodo()}>Delete Todo</button>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
```